# add id to select2 input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

is it possible to add an id to the input type text that select2 is generating? to explain what i want, i have to make a filter based on cities, since there are too many cities, i cant load them all at once, so i made an autocomplete, but the user can choose more cities, so i thought about an autocomplete with select2, i tried using the class, like this

```
$('.select2-search__field').on('keyup', function(e) {
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
```

The problem is, i have more select2 on my page (one with some codes, one with some regions etc.), and i would do useless ajax requests for each of them

Comment: Do you mean reference the ID attribute like so:  $('#select2-search__field').on(.....   ?? If so all you do is add an id attribute to the element and then reference the id attribute as the in the selector.

Comment: it generates an input type text with the class "select2-search__field", im asking if i can add to this element an id, because i have more on my page and i want to differentiate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think outside the box. You might not *have* to put an ID on a Select2 instance.

You need to *somehow* differentiate between different instances of Select2. Maybe an easier approach, which you're already familiar with, would be to wrap them in a `div` which has an ID:

```
<div id=first>
  <!-- one select2 -->
</div>
<div id=second>
  <!-- the other select2-->
</div>
```

You can now access different ones based on the ID of the wrapper.

```
$('#first .select2-search__field')
```

Comment: @lessan - Sometimes we all assume its more difficult that it actually is therefore we overlook the most simple solutions and instantly think it is something far more difficult :)

Comment: @Birdy Sometimes we really need an ID :) In combination with other bits of code (like jquery.validationForm) we can assign an ID as error target (as the select element itself it's hidden)